# Can my PC cope with this screen?

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, resolution

I hope this isn't an abuse of everyone's helpfulness but can anyone work out if my 5-year-old Sony Vaio can cope with [this new monitor](http://www.pcworld.co.uk/gbuk/aoc-e2243fw-21-5-widescreen-led-monitor-07677491-pdt.html) I want to buy (to use as a second monitor). My laptop is a VGN-FJ3S. It has a VGA output.

Here are screen shots of what I think are the graphics card outputs (one for the built in monitor, one for the output):

[image]

[image]

Many thanks for any help you can offer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this](http://www.intel.com/design/chipsets/applnots/301671.htm) datasheet (which can be found by googling for "915GM") your graphics controller can work with a maximum resolution of 2048x1536 which is enough for controlling a 1920x1080 monitor like the one you would like to buy.

Comment: That's great news. I was worried because when I right click on the desktop > Properties > Select the other output, the slide only shows up to: 1600 x 1200. See image: http://imgur.com/1CGeB.png

Comment: I think that's because your current monitor only supports 1600x1200. btw: If this answer helped you, please mark it as correct ;)