# Cannot increase my screen resolution

Tags: graphics-card, display, resolution, intel-graphics

I am trying to install my new monitor but my Graphics Adapter (Mobile Intel(R) 915GM/GMS,910GML Express Chipset Family) does not offer a resolution of 1920x1080 in the [Display Properties > Settings] window. It only offers up to 1360x768.

Can anyone explain to me how I can increase this number to the correct resolution.
The monitor does show my the windows desktop, albeit at a lower resolution which is being stretched to fill the screen, making it look very blurry.

I have installed the "Monitor Drivers" I found on the disk supplied with new monitor, but these do not appear to have made any difference.

The Intel software that comes with the graphics card has an information window containing lots of info about the card and the monitor itself. I have placed [this on a webpage](http://pastebin.com/MgW7LqQe) so you can examine it if helpful.

Many thanks with your help in getting my Christmas present to work!

Patrick

P.S.: Before I got this screen [I checked](https://superuser.com/questions/223669/can-my-pc-cope-with-this-screen) to see if my graphics card could cope with such a large screen.

Comment: You can adjust monitor resolutions only as per Mother Board Chip set and Monitor Capability.

Comment: can you get yourself another cable? it could just be the cable acting up

Comment: I will try that but I think but there is definitly a lot of communication between the screen and PC (various features work) which make me think the wire is probably still okay.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is I am afraid a truly weird issue. SONY appear to have disabled 1920x1080 on my graphics card. However, by following [these instructions](http://norhazlan.blogspot.com/2009/11/how-to-get-1920x1080-full-hd-resolution.html) I have been able to achieve 1919x1080, which is good enough. The text is sharp and I can't notice any aberrations. I thoroughly recommend the instructions on this site.

Comment: ***One*** pixel less????

Answer (score 1):

It seems you're trying to get a multiple monitors configuration (built-in laptop display + secondary monitor). Your built-in display has a max resolution of 1360x768 and your new monitor and graphics card can support 1080p. Your laptop display is the bottleneck here so you can't go higher than that if you have selected to duplicate your desktop on both displays.

In order to give them different resolutions you need to select "**Extend my Windows desktop onto this monitor**" option from Display settings in the Control Panel while both displays are connected. See [this article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307873) if you need help on this.

After that you should be able to get a 1080p resolution from your monitor using either display settings or via Intel graphics adapter application.

Comment: Sorry, I should have made that clear. I am using the extended desktop feature but it still doesn't work (see screenshot http://imgur.com/islww.png).

Comment: hmm, that's weird. have you tried updating your graphics card driver? If updating doesn't work try uninstalling and installing the driver again.

Comment: I'm afraid I've done both those things. I'm coming to the conclusion that it must be the graphics card that is causing the trouble, but I don't know where I can find drivers that will offer the really large screen resolution.

Comment: They're listed here http://www.intel.com/support/chipsets/sb/CS-020149.htm Also try Microsoft Update (an additional option to windows update)

Comment: By the way I have an Acer 2920 laptop with Mobile Intel 965 Express Chipset and I just replicated your configuration to see how it would work. The max resolution it gave me was 1600x1050 although the monitor supports 1080p http://i.imgur.com/8EhtS.png So given that your chipset is even older than mine I wonder if their claim about 1080p support is really true :/

Comment: I hope that isn't the case. Thank-you for doing some tests.

Answer (score 1):

Try unchecking hide modes that monitor can't display and it should give you all the resolutions the GPU can support.

Comment: This appears to be a comment to a 5 year old question.  Comments belong in the comment section, if you cannot submit comments, you should not submit them as answers.  Answers like this are subject to removal, and based on your current answer history, its very likely you won't be able to submit new answers in the future.  The system for quality reasons, will eventual ban you automatically from submitting answers, if you continue to submit answers like this.  Once this happens it cannot be reversed by anyone.

Answer (score 0):

Go in to the BIOS settings and see if you can increase the memory to the graphics device.

I haven't seen this for several years, but I remember re-purposing some 915 boards as servers and decreasing the video memory to  1MB (which was a big mistake) which only allowed 640x480 in monochrome  (I think it was), I then put it up to 8Mb which allowed 1024x768 in true colour... The reason I am saying this is simply I know there is a correlation/direct link between memory given and max resolution it supports.

Comment: Hi Wil, I tried to open up the BIOS (pressing F2 after a restart) but my VAIO PC has something called Pheonix BIOS with very reduced features. I going to look into how to allocate more memory to the graphics card.

Comment: Not sure if this is the answer after all. My video card says it has 128MB allocated dynamically from RAM, which should be ample for 1920x1080.

Answer (score 0):

If you are duplicating the displays then obviously the driver has to pick a single resolution and it picks the lower resolution. Therefore in the duplicate displays option, you do not see a higher resolution in the dropdown.

What worked for me was setting the larger screen as the main display.